# investigate the error with this code?

Tags: python, debugging, runtime

consider the following code when i run it only the line after while loop executed and the if statement seems like it doesnt exist i cannt realize where the error exactly.

```
while True:

    IN = input("   ====================================== \n    CPU scheduler console application: \n   ====================================== \n   1.FCFS \n   2.SJF \n   3.Periority algorithm \n   4.Round robin \n   5.Exit \n   Enter the chosen algorithm to run: ")

if IN == 1:
    Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")
    BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
    ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
    print BurstTimes, '\t\t', ArrivalTimes,
else:
    print 'Good Bye!'
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Judging from the `print`, 2.x

Comment: @alKid, doh! I should have seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the `if` clause:

```
while True:

    IN = raw_input("   ====================================== \n    CPU scheduler console application: \n   ====================================== \n   1.FCFS \n   2.SJF \n   3.Periority algorithm \n   4.Round robin \n   5.Exit \n   Enter the chosen algorithm to run: ")

    if IN == '1': #change this to a string

        Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")
        BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
        ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
        print BurstTimes, '\t\t', ArrivalTimes,
    else:
        print 'Good Bye!'
```

It's a better practice to use `raw_input` and strings instead of `input` - which evaluates your input and might be harmful to your code.

Comment: problem not soleved @alKid

Comment: That's why i'm asking.. what happened?

Comment: The same output, it keep repeating the first line of code

Comment: Is this your whole code and you're positive that the `if` clause is indented properly?

Comment: @user3547642, alKid is right. He has suggested other changes as well such as with the if statement. Are you sure you are applying all the suggested changes?

Comment: Yes it's the whole code what's the problem with if clause ?

Comment: no good byes! it seems like the code consists only of the first line, copy and paste the code to your IDE and see the output

Comment: Problem solved guys it was the indentation of If statement that cause the problem

Comment: @GarethBale If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it as the correct answer.